# Speed up shell script/Performance enhancement of shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to speed up the below shell script? It's taking me a good 40 mins to update about 150000 files everyday. Sure, given the volume of files to create & update, this may be acceptable. I don't deny that. However, if there is a much more efficient way to write this or re-write the logic entirely, I'm open to it. Please I'm looking for some help

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    DATA_FILE_SOURCE="<path_to_source_data/${1}"
    DATA_FILE_DEST="<path_to_dest>"
    
    for fname in $(ls -1 "${DATA_FILE_SOURCE}")
    do
        for line in $(cat "${DATA_FILE_SOURCE}"/"${fname}")
        do
            FILE_TO_WRITE_TO=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F',' '{print $1"."$2".daily.csv"}')
            CONTENT_TO_WRITE=$(echo "${line}" | cut -d, -f3-)
            if [[ ! -f "${DATA_FILE_DEST}"/"${FILE_TO_WRITE_TO}" ]]
            then
                echo "${CONTENT_TO_WRITE}" >> "${DATA_FILE_DEST}"/"${FILE_TO_WRITE_TO}"
            else
                if ! grep -Fxq "${CONTENT_TO_WRITE}" "${DATA_FILE_DEST}"/"${FILE_TO_WRITE_TO}"
                then
                  sed -i "/${1}/d" "${DATA_FILE_DEST}"/"${FILE_TO_WRITE_TO}"
"${DATA_FILE_DEST}"/"${FILE_TO_WRITE_TO}"
                    echo "${CONTENT_TO_WRITE}" >> "${DATA_FILE_DEST}"/"${FILE_TO_WRITE_TO}"
                fi
            fi
        done
    done
```

Comment: Is `$(ls -1 "${DATA_FILE_SOURCE}")` necessary? Use `${DATA_FILE_SOURCE}` instead

Comment: `awk` and `cut` may be heavy. You could use bash substitutions : `T1="${line%%,*}"; line="${line#*,}"; T2="${line%%,*}"; line="${line#*,}"; FILE_TO_WRITE="$T1.$T2.daily.csv"; CONTENT_TO_WRITE="$line"`

Comment: I don't understand the `sed` line. If the dest file exists and it does not already contain the data, delete lines containing the name of the source file? Is that right?

Comment: this would be a lot easier if you were to provide a couple (small) sample input files, describe the operation, and show the expected results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are still parts of your published script that are unclear like the `sed` command. Although I rewrote it with saner practices and much less external calls witch should really speed it up.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

DATA_FILE_SOURCE="<path_to_source_data/$1"
DATA_FILE_DEST="<path_to_dest>"

for fname in "$DATA_FILE_SOURCE/"*; do
  while IFS=, read -r a b content || [ "$a" ]; do
    destfile="$DATA_FILE_DEST/$a.$b.daily.csv"
    if grep -Fxq "$content" "$destfile"; then
        sed -i "/$1/d" "$destfile"
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$content" >>"$destfile"
  done < "$fname"
done
```

Comment: These are great suggestions. @usert4jju7, it's having to run `grep` AND `sed` for every line of every file is what is really killing the performance. You have 150,000 files. If each file has 1,000 lines, then you're invoking grep 150,000,000 times.

Answer (score 0):

0. Make it parallel (as much as you can).

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash
   set -e -o pipefail

   declare -ir MAX_PARALLELISM=20  # pick a limit
   declare -i pid
   declare -a pids

   # ...

   for fname in "${DATA_FILE_SOURCE}/"*; do
     if ((${#pids[@]} >= MAX_PARALLELISM)); then
       wait -p pid -n || echo "${pids[pid]} failed with ${?}" 1>&2
       unset 'pids[pid]'
     fi

     while IFS= read -r line; do
       FILE_TO_WRITE_TO="..."
       # ...
     done < "${fname}" &  # forking here
     pids[$!]="${fname}"
   done

   for pid in "${!pids[@]}"; do
     wait -n "$((pid))" || echo "${pids[pid]} failed with ${?}" 1>&2
   done
   ```

   Here’s a directly runnable skeleton showing how the harness above works (with 36 items to process and 20 parallel processes at most):

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash
   set -e -o pipefail

   declare -ir MAX_PARALLELISM=20  # pick a limit
   declare -i pid
   declare -a pids

   do_something_and_maybe_fail() {
     sleep $((RANDOM % 10))
     return $((RANDOM % 2 * 5))
   }

   for fname in some_name_{a..f}{0..5}.txt; do  # 36 items
     if ((${#pids[@]} >= MAX_PARALLELISM)); then
       wait -p pid -n || echo "${pids[pid]} failed with ${?}" 1>&2
       unset 'pids[pid]'
     fi

     do_something_and_maybe_fail &  # forking here
     pids[$!]="${fname}"
     echo "${#pids[@]} running" 1>&2
   done

   for pid in "${!pids[@]}"; do
     wait -n "$((pid))" || echo "${pids[pid]} failed with ${?}" 1>&2
   done
   ```
1. Strictly avoid external processes (such as `awk`, `grep` and `cut`) when processing one-liners for each line. `fork()`ing is extremely inefficient in comparison to:

   - Running one single `awk` / `grep` / `cut` process on an entire input file (to preprocess all lines at once for easier processing in `bash`) and feeding the whole output into (e.g.) a `bash` loop.
   - Using Bash expansions instead, where feasible, e.g. `"${line/,/.}"` and other tricks from the `EXPANSION` section of the `man bash` page, without `fork()`ing any further processes.
2. Off-topic side notes:

   - `ls -1` is unnecessary. First, `ls` won’t write multiple columns unless the output is a terminal, so a plain `ls` would do. Second, `bash` expansions are usually a cleaner and more efficient choice. (You can use `nullglob` to correctly handle empty directories / “no match” cases.)
   - Looping over the output from `cat` is a (less common) [useless use of `cat`](https://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/useless-use-of-cat/) case. Feed the file into a loop in `bash` instead and read it line by line. (This also gives you more line format flexibility.)

Comment: Hey Thankyou Andrej. Could you please use this on my specific case instead of a generic example

Comment: @usert4jju7 No, obviously, because I don’t have your input data. However, it should be straightforward to modify your script based on the same principles: Run the inner loop in the background and keep track of the number (and return statuses) of background processes. (Presumably, in case if `FILE_TO_WRITE_TO` is not unique, a few extra precautions would be needed.)